# `String' is applied to too many type arguments

Tags: haskell

I'm just learning Haskell and I was trying to write a simple program to eliminate the first n characters from a `String`. This is what I got:

```
cutString :: (Num n, String str) => n -> str -> str

cutString n str = case n of
        0 -> tail str
        n -> cutString (n-1) (tail str)
```

GHC gives me this error though, and I can't figure out why:

```
`String' is applied to too many type arguments
 In the type signature for `cutString':
 cutString :: (Num n, String str) => n -> str -> str
```

Comment: FYI: `cutString = GHC.List.drop`

Comment: Thanks! I just wanted to write my own implementation anyway in order to practice, I just started studying Haskell today

Comment: Note to modern audiences: nowadays `cutString` would also require `Eq` in the context since it uses a literal pattern match.

Comment: @Ben Millwood, thanks for pointing that out. I was wondering why this example no longer works in 2021, even after adjustments from the answers below. Howerver (Num n, Eq n) solves the issue.

Answer (score 54):

`String` is a type, not a typeclass, so you can (must) just use it as-is in the type signature.

```
cutString :: Num n => n -> String -> String
```

Comment: This function does of course have the even simpler type `cutString :: Num n => n -> [a] -> [a]`. Also, `Num` doesn't make much sense in this context, so maybe the type `Integral i => i -> [a] -> [a]` or even `Int -> [a] -> [a]` would be better.

Comment: @dflemstr I'm sure you mean `Integer -> [a] -> [a]` since `Int` is just a rather crude and unprincipled optimisation of `Integer` ;)

Comment: Well, you seldom have more than 536870912 elements in a list... If we want to talk about sematics, I would actually rather opt for `Word`/`Word64` in this case, and then perhaps `Natural` (a non-negative `Integer`) when the base library eventually contains it.

Comment: This statement clears my confusion about the usage of type and type class.

Answer (score 33):

For reference, older GHCs (i.e. 7.2.2 or earlier) used to give this rather more helpful error:

```
Type constructor `String' used as a class
In the type `(Num n, String str) => n -> str -> str'
```

Indeed that is exactly your problem: `String` is a type, and you are using it as a type class. A type class is a collection of types, rather than a single type, e.g. `Integer` and `Double` and `Rational` are all types belonging to the type class `Num`. Type classes appear to the left of `=>` in types, where real types and type variables appear to the right of `=>`.