# Haskell function can get compilation error

Tags: haskell

I can compile the following function in Haskell and it works

```
addVector :: (Num a) => (a, a) -> (a, a) -> (a, a)
addVector (a, b) (c, d) = (a + c, b + d)
```

But I get compilation error for following function

```
addVector3 :: (Float a) => (a, a) -> (a, a) -> (a, a) 
addVector3 (a, b) (c, d) = (a + c, d + b)
```

The only difference between two functions is the type (change `Num` to `Float`)

Error:

```
`Float' is applied to too many type arguments
In the type signature for `addVector3':
addVector3 :: Float a => (a, a) -> (a, a) -> (a, a)
```

Comment: `Num` is a type-_class_, not a type. `Float` is a _type_. You can't just mix and match those.

Answer (score 6):

To expand on the comments, `Float` is a type, while `Num` is a typeclass. What does that mean? Well, `Float` is a single, concrete type: a floating point number. `Num a` means "any type `a`, provided that that type satisfies the requirements of being a `Num`". Examples of `Num` are `Int`, `Float`, and so on.

So it makes perfect sense to say "This function deals with any type, so long as that type is a number of some kind", but no sense at all to say "This function deals with any type, so long as that type is specifically `Float`" (which is how `(Float a) => (a, a) -> (a, a) -> (a, a)` would have to be interpreted, if it made sense). Instead, you can simply say "This function deals with `Float`s", like so:

```
addVector :: (Float, Float) -> (Float, Float) -> (Float, Float)
```

Or you could define a type synonym for this, if you tire of typing `Float` and `,` and `()` over and over:

```
type Vector = (Float, Float)
addVector :: Vector -> Vector -> Vector
```

Comment: It's blindingly obvious when one is sufficiently experienced with Haskell, but one does wonder if the compiler could issue a more helpful message. Is there any point where a type name is valid in that bit of syntax?

Comment: @MatthewWalton [Apparently](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12022602/625403) it used to do so.

Comment: The problem is that there are two errors, first `Float a` has a kind error since `Float` does not take an argument.  Overlooking this error we can then discover a second type error, namely that a type has been used as a class.

Comment: What's the difference between those two errors? I would think every time a class is used as a type that's a kind error.

Comment: Thanks to explain the detail, I'm new to Hahskell

Comment: @amalloy If it had been e.g. `Maybe` instead of `Float` then it would have got past the argument counting part and only erred by more carefully comparing kinds. (In fact in GHC 7.6.3 which is in the latest platform, due to a bug `(Maybe a) => ...` might not err at all.)