# How to define a Haskell function with an argument of "newtype"?

Tags: haskell, types, newtype

I've defined a newtype called Poly. Poly is a list representation of a polynomial (a list of Num's), and I'm trying to define a function "chop" that takes off excess 0's from the end of a Poly.

Chop takes one Poly as an argument, and then returns a Poly. For some reason I'm getting the following error message:

> Expected a constraint, but ‘Poly a’ has kind ‘*’
>       In the type signature for ‘chop’: chop :: Poly a => a -> a

```
newtype Poly a = P [a]

chop :: Poly a => a -> a
chop l = if (last l) == 0 then chop (init l) else l
```

Comment: Same answer as http://stackoverflow.com/q/12018959/791604, though I hesitate to mark this as a duplicate: `Poly a` is a type, so use it as one. `chop :: Poly a -> Poly a`. There may be other problems to fix after that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Haskell, the `=>` character in a type signature denotes a type restriction. This is used in conjunction with Haskell typeclasses in order to abstract away implementation details about functions that can be used at a high level of abstraction.

In your example, `Poly a` is a completely new type according to the type system, not a typeclass, so your function `chop` likely is intended to operate on it directly:

```
chop :: Poly a -> Poly a
chop (P l) = if (last l) == 0 then chop (P $ init l) else P l
```

But wait, this doesn't compile! The restriction comes from the comparison to 0: `(last l) == 0`. Here we're implicitly saying that we want the elements of our `Poly a` to be comparable to zero, or in other words `a` must be an instance of `Num a`. After all, you wouldn't be able to chop a polynomial of type `Poly (Maybe String)`. Our revised type signature is:

```
chop :: Num a => Poly a -> Poly a
chop (P l) = if (last l) == 0 then chop (P $ init l) else P l
```

One thing to take into consideration: because you are using a `newtype` and not a plain old `type`, Haskell is treating your `Poly a` as a completely new type. In order to make it interchangeable with lists, you can use a *type synonym*:

```
type Poly a = [a]
```

This will simplify the implementation of chop:

```
chop :: Num a => Poly a -> Poly a
chop l = if (last l) == 0 then chop (init l) else l
```

Comment: `Eq` is no longer a superclass of `Num`.  If you want it to be equality-comparable to numbers you need `(Eq a, Num a) =>`