# Haskell vector type declaration

Tags: haskell, haskell-vector

I'm writing a comparator to pass to `sortBy` but I can't get the type declaration right. The input is two `Data.Vector`'s, each containing two numbers.

```
-- Comparator to sort a list of individuals by increasing order of fit-0 
--      and for individuals with equal fit-0, with increasing order of fit-1
indCmp :: (Ord a, Num a, Vector a)  => a -> a -> Ordering
indCmp x y
    | (x ! 0) < (y ! 0) = LT
    | (x ! 0) > (y ! 0) = GT
    | (x ! 1) < (y ! 1) = LT -- Can assume (x ! 0) == (y ! 0) here and beneath
    | (x ! 1) > (y ! 1) = GT
    | (x ! 1) == (y ! 1) = EQ
```

GHCI complains:

> Expected a constraint, but 'Vector a' has kind '*'

Comment: I suspect this is a duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018959/string-is-applied-to-too-many-type-arguments/12018975), but with `Vector a` instead of `String`. Does the solution there work for you as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Vector` is a data type, not a class, so your function type should be

```
indCmp :: (Ord a, Num a)  => Vector a -> Vector a -> Ordering
```

When I changed this, it compiled for me.