# How to make a Haskell function calculate ticket prices?

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell and am trying to write a function that does the following:

- asks user to enter "Youth" "Adult" or "Senior" and indicate of the one they pick
- function then calculates total price of tickets (Y = $10.50, A = $20, S = $15)

Sample output: 
Enter type of ticket and count:
Senior 7
Total price is: 95.00

Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
calcPrice :: (String a) => a -> b -> b
calcPrice x y = 
   if x == "Youth" 
      then "Total price :" ++ 10.5 * y
   else if x == "Adult"
      then "Total price :" ++ 20 * y
   else if x == "Senior"
      then "Total price :" ++ 15 * y
   else "Invalid input."
```

...but I get this error:

```
homework8.hs:31:15: error:
    • Expected kind ‘* -> Constraint’, but ‘String’ has kind ‘*’
    • In the type signature: calcPrice :: (String a) => a -> b -> b
   |
31 | calcPrice :: (String a) => a -> b -> b    |
```

Any help is appreciated, but my main questions are:

1. How do we specify the types if we want to output a string and a number?
2. In other variants, an error message appeared that it was not happy about the comparison in the if/else if statements. why?
3. How do I make the function output something if it can only be called with arguments that the user has no idea to input until the message is displayed?

EDIT_________________

Here is the new code after making the changes you all have mentioned:

```
calcPrice :: (Integral a) => String -> a -> String
calcPrice x y = 
   if x == "Youth" 
      then "Total price :" ++ Show(10.5 * y)
   else if x == "Adult"
      then "Total price :" ++ Show(20 * y)
   else if x == "Senior"
      then "Total price :" ++ Show(15 * y)
   else "Invalid input."
```

and I now get this error...

```
homework8.hs:34:31: error:
    • Data constructor not in scope: Show :: a -> [Char]
    • Perhaps you meant variable ‘show’ (imported from Prelude)
   |
34 |       then "Total price :" ++ Show(10.5 * y)    |                               ^^^^

homework8.hs:36:31: error:
    • Data constructor not in scope: Show :: a -> [Char]
    • Perhaps you meant variable ‘show’ (imported from Prelude)
   |
36 |       then "Total price :" ++ Show(20 * y)    |                               ^^^^

homework8.hs:38:31: error:
    • Data constructor not in scope: Show :: a -> [Char]
    • Perhaps you meant variable ‘show’ (imported from Prelude)
   |
38 |       then "Total price :" ++ Show(15 * y)    |                               ^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Comment: See also: [`String' is applied to too many type arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12018959/791604).

Comment: First things first, `but ‘String’ has kind ‘*’` which means you can't apply `String` with a type parameter like `String a`.

Comment: You can't concatenate strings and numbers in Haskell, so do `++ show (20 * y)` instead of `++ 20 * y`, for example, to turn them into strings first. Once you've fixed that, get rid of your type signature and load your code, then use `:t calcPrice` to see the type Haskell infers.

Comment: Apart from the type signature, Haskell is not JS... You just can simply concat a `Num b` value with a `String` type. You have to use the `show` function and make sure that `b` type has a `Show` instance in the type signature.

Comment: `String a => ` does not make much sense, since a `String` is not a typeclass.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I have updated my code but I get new errors (see original post edit).

Comment: @GTI If you have a new problem, please ask a new Question. A Question is not a long-lived document that receives many amendments and much discussion as you make progress, but rather a crystallized problem statement from a particular point in time.

Comment: Please reduce your questions down to one. Reserve the others for other posts. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

> How do we specify the types if we want to output a string and a number?

One way is to give back a *tuple* of a string and a number:

```
calcPrice :: String -> Double -> (String, Double)
calcPrice x y = 
   if x == "Youth" 
      then ("Total price :", 10.5 * y)
   else if x == "Adult"
      then ("Total price :", 20 * y)
   else if x == "Senior"
      then ("Total price :", 15 * y)
   else ("Invalid input.", 0/0)
```

However, as the comments pointed out, in this case it's probably more sensible to encode and append the number part *into* the string. Conversion from many types to String is easily done with the [`show` function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:show) (which is a method of the `Show` (uppercase) typeclass – note how the `show` function you use in your value level code is *lowercase*)

```
calcPrice :: String -> Double -> String
calcPrice x y = 
   if x == "Youth" 
      then "Total price :" ++ show (10.5 * y)
   else if x == "Adult"
      then "Total price :" ++ show (20 * y)
   else if x == "Senior"
      then "Total price :" ++ show (15 * y)
   else "Invalid input."
```

---

The other sub-questions are unclear to me – maybe remove them here and flesh them out as separate questions.

---

Some stylistic remarks:

- Rather than doing a bunch of separate `if x==` statements, it's neater and in general also more efficient to use `case` (which is very flexible in Haskell, and often works even for types that *can't* be equality-compared):

  ```
  calcPrice x y = case x of
     "Youth"  -> "Total price :" ++ show (10.5 * y)
     "Adult"  -> "Total price :" ++ show (20 * y)
     "Senior" -> "Total price :" ++ show (15 * y)
     _        -> "Invalid input."
  ```

  Alternative syntax for the same thing: you can simply write a bunch of separate function clauses for specific values of `x`, rather than only one that accepts *any* `x`

  ```
  calcPrice "Youth" y = "Total price :" ++ show (10.5 * y)
  calcPrice "Adult" y = "Total price :" ++ show (20 * y)
  calcPrice "Senior" y = "Total price :" ++ show (15 * y)
  calcPrice _ _ = "Invalid input."
  ```
- Not just in Haskell, but any language it's good to follow the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). A standard way of this is to define local variables, like

  ```
  calcPrice x y = case x of
     "Youth"  -> totalPrice ++ show (10.5 * y)
     "Adult"  -> totalPrice ++ show (20 * y)
     "Senior" -> totalPrice ++ show (15 * y)
     _        -> "Invalid input."
   where totalPrice = "Total price :"
  ```

  *don't do it this way*, because the actual code-duplication (`++` `show`, `* y`) is still there! Instead, define local *functions* (which are also variables)

  ```
  calcPrice x y = case x of
     "Youth"  -> priceMul 10.5
     "Adult"  -> priceMul 20
     "Senior" -> priceMul 15
     _        -> "Invalid input."
   where priceMul μ = "Total price :" ++ show (μ*y)
  ```
- In a bigger project you should probably separate the “is the input valid?” from the actual calculation logic, else you'll soon have weird errors popping up deep in your code where you never expected them. Worse, if the error is merely “signalled” by a dedicated string value `"Invalid input"`, it becomes very difficult to find where the error did happen.

  Advocates of dynamic languages argue that this is what unit tests are there for, but a static type system reduces the need for that a lot. Specifically, you can accept instead of a string which could easily have lots of invalid values, a type that only *has* those values that are actually valid:

  ```
  data PricingTier = Youth | Adult | Senior

  calcPrice :: PricingTier -> Double -> String
  calcPrice x y = case x of
     Youth  -> priceMul 10.5
     Adult  -> priceMul 20
     Senior -> priceMul 15
   where priceMul μ = "Total price :" ++ show (μ*y)
  ```

Comment: I'd probably argue that the calculation should be done separately from the stringification. ie `calcPrice` should return `Int`, and the caller function should be responsible for prepending "Total price :" and `show`ing  the price. Great answer anyways!